# Как перезапустить Service?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, service, background

Приложение закрыто
Есть сервис работающий в фоне, нужно раз в 5 минут его перезапускать из самого же сервиса (делать restart).

Как это правильно сделать?

stopSerivce ->
startService

Не работает по причине гонки друг с другом.

Comment: Интересно зачем? Может проще перезапускать задачу, которую он выполняет. Если нужен именно перезапуск, то предложу два варианта: `AlarmManager` (планируем запуск через какой-то промежуток времени), или второй сервис (запускаем его, он запускает первый и тут же останавливается)

Comment: @woesss приветствую,остановился на перезапуске задачи)